# Adding default record in rails 4.0 throws symbol missing with polymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a C++ programmer, so I'm not really sure what needs to go into the title. I've stripped the example down as far as I think I can...

Rails 4.1.5, ruby 2.0.0p353, Rubymine 6.3.3, Fedora 20

I have no idea why this issue is happening. I'm trying to populate the database with a default Admin on migrate, but I am getting an undefined method while running `rake db:migrate`.

First, the models

```
class Login < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, polymorphic: true
end


class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :login, :as=>:user, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :login

  def method_missing(symbol, *args)
    self.login.send(symbol,*args)
  end

end
```

Basically, there is a "is_a" relationship between admin and login (In the real application, there are other records that can also be logins, but they have different fields).

Next, the migrations

**_create_logins.rb

```
class CreateLogins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :logins do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :password
      t.references :user, polymorphic: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**_create_admins.rb

```
class CreateAdmins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :admins do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This works great in the rest of the app: I can call get a admin or whatever in a polymorphic fashion from a `login` by calling `login.user`. I can easily add admins in the admin controller. They are all updating the database just fine. Good times are had by all.

Finally, I made a "create default admin:

**_create_default_admin.rb

```
class CreateDefaultAdmin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    down();

    Admin.create(:name=>'Default Admin', :login_attributes=>{:username=>'admin', :password=>'password'})
  end

  def self.down
    Admin.delete_all
  end
end
```

So you can see I'm just trying to create a single Default Admin.

When I try running

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

I get

```
undefined method `name=' for nil:NilClass/home/asdf/RubymineProjects/untitled/app/models/admin.rb:11:in `method_missing'
```

For some reason, the name symbol is not being created, AND loging is nil.

putting a breakpoint in method_missing shows `self.login` is in fact `nil`, which I found odd. Putting the breakpoint on super shows login created. Running AFTER you put a breakpoint on super never gets to `method_missing`. Instead,

```
 unknown attribute: user_id/home/asdf/RubymineProjects/untitled/app/models/admin.rb:7:in `initialize'
```

Questions

1. What is going on here? (What did I do wrong, why is it wrong, and why am I getting this weird behaviour?)
2. What is the correct way to add default values to a database?

Update: the error happens if I move the create to `seed.rb` as well.
Update2: I've determined that the cause of the problem is the method missing (removing that seems to fix the problem). Now to the why the method missing is bad, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I'm not calling `super` in method missing. You must call `super` in method missing if the message isn't handled.

*THE MORE YOU KNOW*